# Can't figure out how to start postgres on port 5432 in windows

Tags: postgresql, windows

### Setting up Postgres on Windows for frontend web dev

This is not my area of expertise (frontend guy), but I need postgres simply running on my side to connect with the test DB for the project I'm working on:

I have to run this before I start my project: `dropdb [db_name] && createdb [db_name] && npm run migration:run:dev`

When I do so, I get the typical:

```
dropdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

This tells me that postgres isn't running on port 5432, which I verified in Resource Monitor and inside pgAdmin... in pgAdmin, all the PIDs are NOT 5432 and when I try to change the port to 5432 (although, already set to that), I get:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have postgres installed via the packaged installer, and I've tried various solutions, such as:
https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/10/how-to-start-stop-restart-postgresql-server.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466190/cant-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432 (I don't need remote connections)

### Note(s)

I use homebrew to do this on my mac in like 2 commands... but services doesn't work with linuxbrew. I don't think my network is an issue if my mac has no problem with it on the same network.

I'm thinking something could be running on port 5432, but nothing appears to be in Resource Monitor.

### Output from `netstat -tlna | grep 5432`

Nothing...

### Edits

1. It seems the PID in Network Resource and pgAdmin don't refer to the port it's running on???

Comment: So, **does** Postgres run? And "PIDs" have not relation to a port whatsoever. But if you can look at the PIDs from within pgAdmin you can clearly connect - so how did you do that?

Comment: The message "*Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432?*"  indicates that you are not running on Windows, but on some kind of Linux. Because on Windows that error message does not include the reference to the domain socket.

Comment: Give us the output of `netstat -tlna | grep 5432`. Not sure of the exact syntax for Mac!

Comment: _Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)_ is an error produced by Windows, 10061 being WSAECONNREFUSED. But as mentioned in previous comments, the dropdb message does not come from Windows. You mention you don't need remote connections but that seems to be contradicted by these error messages.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I went to pgAdmin, found my server on the left, connected via entering my password. Also, I'm using bash in hyper.js (terminal). That's the error it gives me and I'm definitely running windows...

Comment: @Vérace no output (connected to server via pgAdmin before I ran this)

Comment: @DanielVérité If I use the dropdb command above, I get the exact some error message as I posted and I'm using bash on windows. Here's what I'm doing and what works on my mac - I have installed and run postgres 10 via homebrew, I run the command given by the backend DEV (dropdb line above), and it creates the information I need, then I `npm run dev`... There isn't an actual, stored DB right now, as far as I know. We're just using created data for testing.

Comment: And without the `grep`? As I said, I'm not completely sure of the commands on the Mac - I want to see all the ports which are listening on the machine and then see if one of them is 5432. You might want to `grep -i postgres` for every line of the output off all listening ports - one command just gives number, others give the programme name. The command I gave shows all on Linux - check out the Mac command(s);.

Comment: @Vérace I'm not working on a mac. This is a problem I'm experiencing setting up on windows.

Comment: OK - so you're using a Windows server (why?) with a Windows client? I saw Mac in the question - but that was you saying it'd have been much easier there - hence my "why?" above! :-) Don't have too much experience with Windows servers (thank you Lord! :-) ) - can you download Process Exporer and/or Process Monitor from sysinternals? Also, check out their ports/TCP stuff (TCPView? it's been a while). They are the dogs for Windows diagnostics stuff. Poke around - you might get something?

Comment: @Vérace Hmm, seems overkill. I'm literally just installing postgres from their site, using the installer, and trying to start it so the command line above works. I haven't set anything up... I don't even know what the difference between a windows server and... a windows client? Idk, I'm just installing this. It's safe to assume besides what I've stated in my question, I don't know about anything else.

Comment: I'm not sure about there being a default admin tool with PostgreSQL now apart from psql (which is a CLI). Maybe try SQuirreL? I've found it to be great in the past!